# Recreate Rails 2.3 Production Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment, production-environment

I recently took over development of a Rails 2.3.5 application running on Ruby 1.8.7 that hasn't seen much progress since 2009. Having been spoiled by Bundler I'm finding it difficult to setup a development environment locally that matches what is in production.

Through trial and error I've attempted to get the required gems with proper versions running, but I still encounter errors.

Can anyone recommend a more reliable or automated approach to duplicating a production environment for development?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the production environment hosted using a VPS/Cloud service that is easy to clone? You could just backup the production image and then create a new instance using that image, and everything should be exact. Then just make a few config changes and you can use it as your development/staging environment. This should be pretty easy to do on Rackspace Cloud Servers or Amazon EC2.

Comment: It's actually hosted on Engine Yard so I think that means EC2. I'll look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and set up Bundler to work with Rails 2.3, then just use Gemfiles as normal

[Bundler with Rails 2.3](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html)

Comment: That's what I attempted, and I'm still working towards that. There are just so many old gems in this app that it isn't going smoothly. Thanks.

Comment: Yup sounds familiar - have a Rails 2.2 app that I have to maintain and continue to develop. Only approach I've tried with this app is RVM and Gemsets, setting up the Gemsets on both the development machine and the production server with the same list of Gems. Abit of a pain to source the Gems in some cases with the easiest way I've found is just to take the latest commit date from the SVN repository before the application went live and then search Github / Ruby Gems etc for a version of the Gem that was current at that time.